# Output generated SQL query in CakePHP Unit Test

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

My unit test is very simple. My question isn't so much as 'whats wrong with the test/query' as it is how to trouble shoot these issues in APP/test.php by getting a generated SQL Query.

The following is my Unit Test:

```
public function testMatchingPasswords() {
    debug($this->User->save($this->genericSaveData));
}
```

And I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'User.username' in 'where clause'
```

I understand the problem, and if I could see the generated SQL Query, I should be able to troubleshoot the issue further and resolve it. But on test.php it doesn't display the generated SQL Query. How can I make the test.php more verbose so that I can see what query is being generated?

Comment: Queries are always displayed at the bottom. What is your schema/fixture file here? Sure it contains the username field?

Comment: Queries apparently don't show for $this->Model->save when there is an exception. The question isn't what is the problem, but why isn't the query there, or how do you output the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though the best bet is to catch the PDOException and inspect the stack trace, as that includes the prepared query.

So say you are having trouble with `$this->User->save($data)` you could do this:

```
try {
    $this->User->save($data);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    var_dump(array_slice($e->getTrace(), 0, 3));
}
```

The `_execute` call should be fairly near the top, with the generated query included in `args`.